# sql join on string = integer to work on any RDBMS

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join, adodb

I need to `join` two tables on column, which in one table is defined as *string* and in other as *integer*. In both columns actual data stored is *integers*. This is given to me by design - I can't change this.

So when I do join `MySQL` is fine - it does conversion silently. `PostgreSQL` complains. There are `CAST` operators, which I can add to query to have *strings* converted to *integers*, but CAST function is defined in different RDBMSs differently.

Can I write this query in the way that it works in all (or many) RDBMSs? Alternatively, is there DB abstraction layer, which can do this for me? `ADODB` is already used in the project, but I can't see if and how it can be helpful in solving this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: `CAST(expr AS type)` is ANSI SQL and should work in all RDBMS

Comment: This is how it is defined in MySQL: CAST(VAR AS UNSIGNED) and here it is in PostgreSQL: CAST(VAR AS INTEGER)

Comment: why not use `INTEGER` type in mysql as well?

Comment: I don't think such type exists in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: I do think it exists: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Well, I've just run it in MySQL 5.5.x to make sure and getting error for 'integer'. 'unsigned' works, but it is no good...

Comment: Seems like you're right. Oh god, it seems like mysql was developed with as much incompatibilities as possible :-S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can't `CAST` to `INT` in the same way for each database due to data types, you can cast your numeric field to `CHAR`:

```
CAST(a.numeric_Field AS CHAR(5))` = b.stringfield
```

That will work on Postgresql, MySQL, SQL Server, not sure about others.

Comment: I'll give it a try and report back. It is not ideal because: a) joining on 'string' column/values is slower than on integers b) the actual data is integers, so this is rather 'wrong' way of doing things.

Comment: This indeed works. Performance of query 2x worse and I didn't find yet possibility to re-write it to run faster, but this - at least - works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also cast *string* value to int.

```
SELECT tb1.* FROM tb1
  INNER JOIN tb2         
  ON tb1.id = tb2.stringfield::int;
```

Comment: Where did the `::int` come from?

Comment: This seems to be Postgres specific syntax.. but it worked for me :)